# Display the values in Bytes and MB

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to make an IF condition, to appear in my MessageBox, the value in Bytes if the `freeSpaceInC/(1000000)<1024` and if it is `>1024` to appear in MB.

I have the next code, but It can't be made ​​simpler ? and how I can make to recognize the next if  `if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)`:

```
static void Main()
{    
    var drive = new DriveInfo("c");
    long freeSpaceInC = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

    var drive1 = new DriveInfo("d");
    long freeSpaceInD = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

    if ((freeSpaceInC / (1000000) < 1024) && (freeSpaceInD / (1000000) < 1024))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There is " + freeSpaceInC / (1000000) + "B free in C: and " + freeSpaceInD / (1000000) + "B free in D:. Do you want to continue the installation?", "MATLAB_R2008a_ENU_EU", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }
    else if ((freeSpaceInC / (1000000) > 1024) && (freeSpaceInD / (1000000) > 1024))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There is " + freeSpaceInC / (1000000) + "MB free in C: and " + freeSpaceInD / (1000000) + "MB free in D:. Do you want to continue the installation?", "MATLAB_R2008a_ENU_EU", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }
    else if ((freeSpaceInC / (1000000) > 1024) && (freeSpaceInD / (1000000) < 1024))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There is " + freeSpaceInC / (1000000) + "MB free in C: and " + freeSpaceInD / (1000000) + "B free in D:. Do you want to continue the installation?", "MATLAB_R2008a_ENU_EU", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }
    else if ((freeSpaceInC / (1000000) < 1024) && (freeSpaceInD / (1000000) > 1024))
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There is " + freeSpaceInC / (1000000) + "B free in C: and " + freeSpaceInD / (1000000) + "MB free in D:. Do you want to continue the installation?", "MATLAB_R2008a_ENU_EU", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
        fm1.ShowDialog();
        fm1.Close();
    }            
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about your conditions? What do you want to check?

Comment: the freeSpaceInC give me the space available from C:\ drive, and the number is > 1024 then in MessageBox to appear "number " MB and if the number is <1024 then in MessageBox to appear "number" B . The difference is in MessageBox where after number appear MB or B

Comment: And what is that?  "/ (1000000) " I just think you doing something wrong.

Comment: You must declare `dialogResult` outside the conditions

Comment: the value that I get is in bytes, and I wanted to transform the bytes in MB

Comment: Then why do you still divide by 1,000,000 in the message when you are saying B instead of MB?

Comment: and where  is supposed to be declared ?

Comment: if you want, you can ignore the /1000000 and the number is in Bytes and if not the result is in MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go way simpler:

```
static void Main()
{    
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("There is " + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInC) + " free in C: and " + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInD) + " free in D:. Do you want to continue the installation?", "MATLAB_R2008a_ENU_EU", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
        fm1.ShowDialog();
        fm1.Close();
    }            
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}

private static string toReadableSize(int size)
{
    if(size < 1024)
        return size + "B";

    if(size < 1024*1024)
        return Math.Round(((float)size / 1024), 2) + "KB";

    if(size < 1024*1024*1024)
        return Math.Round(((float)size / (1024*1024)), 2) + "MB";

    return Math.Round(((float)size / (1024*1024*1024)), 2) + "GB";
}
```

Comment: That second return should have `size` instead of `freeSpaceInC`

Comment: I can't understand why there are 1000000 divider, instead of 1024 (to check if there are < 1024 KiloBytes)

Comment: @SergeiZhukov because the OP wants B or MB, and not KB, but we could add it

Comment: Yes, but if we divide by 1000000 we get some unknown value (lets assume it's 1024*1024), so the value in MB, so why if there are less than 1024 MB we writing B? I think we should write B only if there are less than 1 MB (1024 KB)

Comment: @SergeiZhukov does this looks better?

Comment: `+ toReadableSize(freeSpaceInC) + " free in D"` is probably copy/pasta too. :)

Comment: @WaiHaLee yup, well seen

Comment: I changed  + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInC) but in MessageBox is displayed the same value for both, the value for C:\ drive

Comment: I want to say + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInD)

Comment: So  what I need to do, to this code display in MessageBox the freespace from D:\ Drive?? not only from c:\ drive

Comment: The problem is : the Message box looks like: "There is 9.93GB free in C and 9.93GB free in D:. Do you want to continue ....? ". On my machine I have 9.93 free space in C but in D I have 114GB....

Comment: I changed my code with your code, but I left          .........................................var drive = new DriveInfo("c");
            long freeSpaceInC = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

            var drive1 = new DriveInfo("d");
            long freeSpaceInD = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

Comment: and in private static string toReadableSize I changed (int size) with (long size )

Comment: You understand what I try to say ?

Comment: I find the error, that was in my part of code when I declared long freeSpaceInD =drive1.ToatalFreeSpace instead of drive1 I wrote drive. Thank you !

Comment: @PopDaniela don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Or you could go to a generic solution with something similar to this:

```
string TranslateSize(long value) {
    var table =
        Enumerable
        .Range(0, 5)
        .Select(x => {
            var @base = (long)Math.Pow(1024, x);
            return new {
                Start = x != 0 ? @base : 0,
                End = 1024 * @base,
                Divider = @base,
                Suffix = ""
            };})
        .Zip(
            new []{"B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"},
            (l, r) => new {
                l.Start,
                l.End,
                l.Divider,
                Suffix = r
            });

    var result = table.Single(x => x.Start <= value && value < x.End);
    return result;
}
```

Make a class of it and make the translation table static.

Comment: This is like using a tank to kill a fly... But it's a nice solution if the OP can use Linq ;) . I would just write `return table.Single...` instead of using a variable.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, sure. I would make a class from it so the `table` is initialize once. Perhaps, make an extension method from it, and use it as such: `value.ToReadableSize()`